# What would an object made from photon matter look like?

Tags: physics, universe, quantum

In this [article](https://physicsworld.com/a/physicists-create-molecules-of-light/),two photons have been made as to interact with each other.  So assuming we managed to make, lets say, a meter by meter cube out of photon molecules that is stable, how would it:

A) Look (i.e. interact with non molecular light that reflects back to the eye).

B) Interact with normal matter.

C)Theoretical properties.

Comment: Not the first question on "solid light" today, [strangely enough](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/161673/62341).

Answer (score 4):

There's no such thing as photon matter. What was made were some interesting states of regular matter interacting with photons. The substrate remains regular matter. It will look like regular matter (in this case, being a gas, probably not very interesting) and it will interact like matter.

The theoretical properties might be very interesting and varied, but they almost certainly *won't* involve the creation of exotic matter with strange and exciting interactions with regular matter.

For other vaguely related things, read up on surface plasmons and [polaritons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polariton), which also involve coupling light with regular matter and some interesting effects coming out but without somehow creating a new kind of matter.

Comment: This is just a 'what if'.

Comment: @Seraphim the problem with that is that you're asking for people's opinions on the properties of impossible material, which is equivalent to asking how magic should work. May as well flag your own question as off topic or too broad, and beat the rush ;-)

Comment: That's...actually a good point.